# Does using WordPress alongside my CMS violate any search engine guidelines?

Tags: seo, blog

I created my own CMS for my website, so it doesn't use any general CMS. I don't have a blog right now but I plan to use WordPress core to build one (like `www.myweb.com/blog`). I will have two admin pages: one for my website & another for just my blog.

I have no time to create my own blog system because it's a complex system for comments, image uploads, and categories. So for faster development, I will just create a theme and use WP core for the CMS.

Will my plan violate any search engine's terms or rules for SEO? Do Google, Bing, Yahoo, Soso, or Yandex advise against this?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly it will `NOT` harm your rankings using various content management systems within another or running along side another.

Many international large businesses use WP and other CMS along side their bespoke CMS such as Sony, Philips etc. There is no rule, or hidden code to detect and punish people who do this... You could have 1000 CMS running along side each other, as long as the content is good, it rank without punishment.